# Dynamically set validation message & minimum on radio button change in Angular

Tags: angular, validation, dynamic

Trying to have a validation message and minimum value be dynamically set based off a radio button.  Currently there are 2 radio buttons for either 9 or 18 holes and then a corresponding input (golf handicap calculator app).  The idea is if user selects 9 holes radio button the subsequent input should set a minimum value of 9 along with a validation message saying to enter a value of at least 9.  Then if user switches to 18 hole radio button the minimum now becomes 18 and the message replaces 9 with 18.  The kicker is that I have a formArray with formGroups so there will be at least 3 formGroups and up to 20 so I have to be able to get them in the formArray and work appropriately for each formGroup.

I've tried a bunch of different scenarios.  I currently have a valueChanges & statusChanges observable that runs, one enables/disables a button on the valueChange and on the statusChanges a function runs that does calculations and displays it on the page dynamically.  My thought was to use the status or value changes observable and do something like grab the radio button value, if it is 'nineHoles' then setValidators and pass in my custom validation with the updated values and then at the end updateValueAndValiditity.

While that did technically work, when I ran it the stack became full and I got all sorts of errors due to the number of times called from observable.  I also looked into rxjs disctinctUntilUnchanged to help resolve this full stack issue and that did help however things still don't seem to line up in terms of if I change the radio button in one form group it is effecting others.  For example if I change the radio button from 9 to 18 in the first formGroup and the second formGroup still has 9 selected, that second formGroup is going based off the first formGroup being 18 (even though the second form group has 9 selected)

Here is the pertinent part of my TS code:

```
get roundInputs(): FormArray{
    return <FormArray>this.roundForm.get('roundInputs')
}

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.roundForm = this.fb.group({
        roundInputs: this.fb.array([ this.buildRoundForm(), this.buildRoundForm(), this.buildRoundForm() ])
    })
};

buildRoundForm() : FormGroup {
    const roundFormGroup = this.fb.group({
        userRoundScore: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(this.eighteenHoleRoundMin), this.roundInputValidation(this.eighteenHoleRoundMin)]],
        courseRating: [67.5, [Validators.required]],
        slopeRating: [117, [Validators.required]],
        roundSelection: ['eighteenHoles', [Validators.required]]
    })

    roundFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        if (this.calcBtnDisabled && value) {
        this.calcBtnDisabled = false;
        }
    })

    roundFormGroup.statusChanges.subscribe(status => {
        this.calcScoreDifferential();
    })

    return roundFormGroup
}

roundInputValidation(score: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
        if ((control.touched || control.dirty) && control.value < score) {
            return { 'invalidForm': true };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]="roundForm">
    <div formArrayName="roundInputs" *ngFor="let round of roundInputs.controls; let roundCount=index">
        <div [formGroupName]="roundCount">

            <!-- Round number -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label attr.for="{{'round_number' + roundCount}}">Round Number: </label>
                <span id="{{'round_number' + roundCount}}"> {{roundCount+1}}</span>
            </div>

            <!-- 9 or 18 hole selection -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Round Selection: </label>
                <div>
                    <label attr.for="{{'nineHoles' + roundCount}}">
                        <input type="radio" id="{{'nineHoles' + roundCount}}" value="nineHoles" formControlName="roundSelection">
                        9 Holes
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label attr.for="{{'eighteenHoles' + roundCount}}">
                        <input type="radio" id="{{'eighteenHoles' + roundCount}}" value="eighteenHoles" formControlName="roundSelection">
                        18 Holes
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- round score input -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label attr.for="{{'userRoundScore' + roundCount}}">Round Score: </label>
                <input id="{{'userRoundScore' + roundCount}}" type="number" formControlName="userRoundScore" min="18">
                <br>
                <span *ngIf="round.get('userRoundScore')?.errors?.['invalidForm']" style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">Enter in a round of at least 18</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do a custom validator that involve two or more FormControls you have two options:

1. Make a custom validator over the whole formGroup (this makes that
   it's executed each change on each formControl of the formGroup). This works very well if the formGroup it's only related to the two controls, but if the formGroup have more conrols remember that the validator is executed each change.

   ```
     formArray=new FormArray([this.createGroup(),this.createGroup()])
     createGroup()
     {
       return new FormGroup({
         roundSelection:new FormControl(''),
         userRoundScore:new FormControl('')
       },this.customValidationGroup)
     }
     customValidationGroup(control:AbstractControl)
     {
       const form=control as FormGroup
         return +form.get('userRoundScore')?.value>=
                                   +form.get('roundSelection')?.value?null:
                             {minValue:'required minimum '
                                           +form.get('roundSelection')?.value}
     }
   ```

   The .html, e.g.

   ```
   <div *ngFor="let group of formArray.controls" [formGroup]="group">
     <input formControlName="roundSelection">
     <div>
       <input formControlName="userRoundScore">
       <div class="error">{{group.errors?.minValue}}</div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Make a custom validator over the formControl and call to
   updateValueAndValidity when change the another FormControl

   ```
     formArray2=new FormArray([this.createGroup2(),this.createGroup2()])
     createGroup2()
     {
       return new FormGroup({
         roundSelection:new FormControl(''),
         userRoundScore:new FormControl('',this.customValidationControl)
       })
     }

     customValidationControl(control:AbstractControl)
     {
       const form=control.parent
       if (form)
       return +form.get('userRoundScore')?.value>=
                      +form.get('roundSelection')?.value?null:
              {minValue:'required minimum '
                              +form.get('roundSelection')?.value}

       return null
     }
   ```

   The .html, e.g.

   ```
   <div *ngFor="let group of formArray2.controls" [formGroup]="group">
     <input formControlName="roundSelection" 
            (input)="group.get('userRoundScore')?.updateValueAndValidity()">
     <div>
        <input formControlName="userRoundScore">
        <div class="error"> 
           {{group.get('userRoundScore')?.errors?.minValue}}
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6hsd8s?file=src%2Fmain.ts) with the two approach

NOTE: In the stackblitz are not enabled strict mode, possible you need create a getters of the formArrays and I don't use formBuilder, but the idea it's the same using formBuilder or not

NOTE:2 Don't forget use the "+" to convert to number in the custom error

**Update** I choose show/hide the error using .css, see that in the first example the .css are like

```
   .error{
      visibility:hidden;
      color:red;
      font-size:.8rem;
    }
    //The ng-invalid is the formGroup, not the input
    .ng-invalid input.ng-touched + .error{
      visibility:visible
    }
```

In the second one the .css is like

```
.error{
  visibility:hidden;
  color:red;
  font-size:.8rem;
}
 //here the "invalid" is the input
input.ng-touched.ng-invalid + .error{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

**Update 2** brief explain of my customValidation:

A custom validator should return: null if is valid, another thing (generally an object) when is not valid. I make so quickly the customValidationControl. step by step (with comments):

```
customValidationControl(control:AbstractControl)
  {
    const form=control.parent //get the "form"
    if (form)  //we need be sure the "form" exist
    {
        //get the value of userRoundScore and roundSelection
        //see the "+" to convert to number the value of the formControl
        //and the "safe operator" ? because typescript give error
        //because a form.get(...) can be null
        const userRoundScore=+form.get('userRoundScore')?.value;
        const roundSelection=+form.get('roundSelection')?.value;

        //Instead of use the the conditional operator 
        //we can use "if"
        if (userRoundScore>=roundSelection) //if all is Ok
            return null
        
        //else
        return {minValue:'required minimum '+roundSelection}
    }
     return null //if the form is not yet also return all is Ok
  }
```

NOTE: we can create a formGroup with a formGroup inside like

```
  createGroup()
  {
    return new FormGroup({
      slopeRating:new FormControl('')
      courseRating:new FormControl('')
      group:new FormGroup({
         roundSelection:new FormControl(''),
         userRoundScore:new FormControl('')
        },this.customValidationGroup)
      })
  }
```

Comment: In the first option couldn't I just create a nested formGroup for the roundSelection and userRoundScore that way I have a form group specifically just for the controls I'm checking?  I'm also not following your customValidationControl method in terms of what the return is

Comment: @EricPetela, a custom validator should return: null if is valid, another thing (generally an object) when is not valid. I use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator):it's only `variable=(condition)?value if condition true:value if condition false`. It's can be change by `if (condition) variable=value1 else variable=value2`. I just update the answer adding a brief explain